# using dllimport

Tags: c#, pinvoke, name-decoration

I'm trying to use the `DllImport` attribute in the following code:

```
[DllImport("grfinger.dll",EntryPoint="_grstartenroll@4")]
public static extern int startenroll(int context);
```

to get the function name I used dumpbin /export. When I run the code I get the following exception:

`Unable to find an entry point name '_grstartenroll@4' in DLL 'grfinger.dll'`.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 5):

_grstartenroll@4 is the [decorated function name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ax8kbk1.aspx) in the dll.

That looks like standard calling convention naming, you could try:

```
[DllImport("grfinger.dll",EntryPoint="_grstartenroll@4", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall]
public static extern int startenroll(int context);
```

Otherwise I would try and get the undecorated function name, you can pipe the output of dumpbin to undname like this:

> dumpbin /exports grfinger.dll |
>   undname _grstartenroll@4

and then use the undecorated function name in your dll import.

Comment: +1, Besides dumpbin, you can also check this free tool: "Dependency Walker" (a.k.a. "depends") http://www.dependencywalker.com/.

Comment: Dependency Walker is a good alternative, and such a small download

Answer (score 0):

Without knowning anything about the specific function or library: I believe specifying the entrypoint as `entrypoint="startenroll"` or `entrypoint="#4"` instead of the dumpbin output might help.